# Best way to store associations on two id of same table?

Tags: sql, database

I have one classic table User :

```
id_user
name
firstname
...
```

I want to store a list of associated users without any other information, just to store associated users, like :

```
id_user1
id_user2
```

If I create a table with only this two columns, it will not check that the user id is existing in the user table :

```
create table AssociatedUsers
(
"ID_USER1" VARCHAR2(10),
"ID_USER2" VARCHAR2(10),
CONSTRAINT "ASSOCIATED_USERS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_USER1", "ID_USER2")
);
```

I can also create the table with an id and two foreign key, but is this really necessary knowing I don't need this generated id ?

```
create table AssociatedUsers
    (
    "ID_ASSOCIATED_USERS" INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    "ID_USER1" VARCHAR2(10),
    "ID_USER2" VARCHAR2(10),
    CONSTRAINT "ASSOCIATED_USERS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_USER1", "ID_USER2"),
    CONSTRAINT "USER1_FK" FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES User(id_user),
    CONSTRAINT "USER2_FK" FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES User(id_user)
    );
```

Comment: Hi - why don't you just create the FKs on the columns in the first version of the table you've shown. I'm not sure why you added the column "ID_ASSOCIATED_USERS" when you added the FKs?

Comment: Yes sure, I was a little tired I think, you're right, I'm not obliged to add this column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I do this :

```
create table ASSOCIATEDUSERS
(
"USER1" VARCHAR2(10),
"USER2" VARCHAR2(10),
CONSTRAINT "ASSOCIATED_USERS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("USER1", "USER2"),
CONSTRAINT "USER1_FK" FOREIGN KEY (USER1) REFERENCES USER("ID_USER"),
CONSTRAINT "USER2_FK" FOREIGN KEY (USER2) REFERENCES USER("ID_USER")
);
```

And in my hibernate hbm mapping I have this :

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.myproject.AssociatedUser" table="ASSOCIATEDUSERS"  >
        <composite-id name="id" class="com.myproject.AssociatedUserId">
            <key-property name="user1" type="string">
                <column name="USER1" length="10" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="user2" type="string">
                <column name="USER2" length="10" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <many-to-one name="user1" class="com.myproject.User" insert="false" update="false">
            <column name="IDUSER"/>
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="user2" class="com.myproject.User" insert="false" update="false">
            <column name="IDUSER"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```